# How to understate gdb print expression

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gdb

I am debugging a [e2term](https://github.com/o-ran-sc/ric-plt-e2/blob/master/RIC-E2-TERMINATION/sctpThread.cpp) open source code which is crashing at line 2752 and/or 2753 using gdb which unease [Prometheus counter library](https://github.com/jupp0r/prometheus-cpp).  I get below value of a expression in gdb

```
(gdb) p  *message.peerInfo->counters[OUT_SUCC][MSG_COUNTER][ProcedureCode_id_E2setup]
$20 = {
  static metric_type = prometheus::MetricType::Counter,
  gauge_ = {
    static metric_type = prometheus::MetricType::Gauge,
    value_ = {
      static _S_min_alignment = 8,
      static _S_alignment = 8,
      _M_i = 17,
      static is_always_lock_free = <error reading variable: Missing ELF symbol "std::atomic<double>::is_always_lock_free".>
    }
  }
}
```

How can I understand the output of this expression? What is static metric_type, gauge static _S_alignment and other fields are?

Full gdb dump

```
/home/ubuntu#gdb -p 174190
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Attaching to process 174190
[New LWP 174191]
[New LWP 174192]
[New LWP 174193]
[New LWP 174194]
[New LWP 174195]
[New LWP 174330]
[New LWP 174331]
[New LWP 174332]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

warning: Target and debugger are in different PID namespaces; thread lists and other data are likely unreliable.  Connect to gdbserver inside the container.
__pthread_clockjoin_ex (threadid=140319039407872, thread_return=0x0, clockid=<optimized out>, abstime=<optimized out>, block=<optimized out>) at pthread_join_common.c:145
145 pthread_join_common.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) n

Thread 8 "e2" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7f9e91ffb700 (LWP 174331)]
0x000056489026f7f0 in std::atomic<double>::load(std::memory_order) const ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000056489026f7f0 in std::atomic<double>::load(std::memory_order) const ()
#1  0x000056489026f59d in prometheus::Gauge::Change(double) ()
#2  0x000056489026f4d0 in prometheus::Gauge::Increment(double) ()
#3  0x000056489026f4a2 in prometheus::Gauge::Increment() ()
#4  0x00005648902565e6 in prometheus::Counter::Increment() ()
#5  0x00005648901f4712 in receiveXappMessages (sctpMap=0x56489237c1a0, rmrMessageBuffer=..., ts=...) at /opt/e2/RIC-E2-TERMINATION/sctpThread.cpp:2752
#6  0x00005648901fb59e in listener (params=0x7ffdc4328f50) at /opt/e2/RIC-E2-TERMINATION/sctpThread.cpp:972
#7  0x00007f9e9b598de4 in ?? () from target:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x00007f9e9b6ac609 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:477
#9  0x00007f9e9b2a0133 in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95
```

added some more gdb output

```
(gdb) p *message.peerInfo
$12 = {
  fileDescriptor = 56,
  hostName = "::3134:3033:3139:3033%925905977", '\000' <repeats 993 times>,
  portNumber = "39754\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000",
  enodbName = "gnb_734_373_040db5a4\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000",
  asnData = '\000' <repeats 262143 times>,
  asnLength = 0,
  mtype = 0,
  isConnected = false,
  gotSetup = false,
  sctpParams = 0x7ffdc4328f50,
  counters = {{{0x0, 0x7f9e84020e50, 0x7f9e84021130, 0x7f9e84021a10, 0x0, 0x7f9e84021730, 0x0, 0x7f9e84021d30, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7f9e84021170, 0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x7f9e84020fc0, 0x
        0x7f9e84021b80, 0x0, 0x7f9e840218a0, 0x0, 0x7f9e84021ec0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7f9e84021300, 0x0, 0x0}}, {{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7f9e84021cf0, 0x7f9e840222f0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7f
        0x7f9e840225d0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7f9e84022180, 0x7f9e84022460, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7f9e840227a0, 0x7f9e84022a60, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}}, {{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
        0x7f9e84022c10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7f9e84022f30, 0x7f9e84022bd0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7f9e84022da0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7f9e840230c0, 0x7f9e84023380, 0
        0x0}}, {{0x0, 0x0, 0x7f9e84023520, 0x7f9e84023800, 0x7f9e84023ae0, 0x0, 0x7f9e84023dc0, 0x0, 0x7f9e840240a0, 0x7f9e840243c0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x7f9e840236
        0x7f9e84023970, 0x7f9e84023c50, 0x0, 0x7f9e84023f30, 0x0, 0x7f9e84024210, 0x7f9e84024550, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}}, {{0x0, 0x7f9e84024380, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
        0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x7f9e84024810, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}}, {{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 
        0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}}},
  isSingleStream = false,
  singleStreamId = 0
}
(gdb) 

(gdb) ptype ConnectedCU_t  ---->in soruce code  ConnectedCU_t *peerInfo 
type = struct ConnectedCU {
    int fileDescriptor;
    char hostName[1025];
    char portNumber[32];
    char enodbName[64];
    char asnData[262144];
    size_t asnLength;
    int mtype;
    bool isConnected;
    bool gotSetup;
    sctp_params_t *sctpParams;
    prometheus::Counter *counters[6][2][13];
    bool isSingleStream;
    int singleStreamId;
}
```

Comment: What ***is*** `message.peerInfo->counters[OUT_SUCC][MSG_COUNTER][ProcedureCode_id_E2setup]` (and all the involved variables)? Do you have a [mre] of the code to show us, with all structure, array and variable definitions?

Comment: I have just added value of   message.peerInfo   and  counters as you asked in main thread at the  last. this is a 3rd party code i m debuging hence could not make a minimum reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help me to understand the output of this expression?

Whatever `class` is the type of `$20` has a `static` data member named `metric_type`.

To understand what it *means* you have to *read* and *understand* the source code. There is no substitute to doing that, and asking here is unlikely to help, unless you just happen to find someone familiar with that code.